# KTDataTable: put data inside modal with the button inside KTDatatable using javascript

Tags: javascript, metronic

i'm using ktdatatable and inside it, i have this code on one of the field of the ktdatatable.

```
                field: 'Actions',
                title: 'Actions',
                sortable: false,
                width: 110,
                overflow: 'visible',
                autoHide: false,
                template: function(data) {
                    var button = '';
                    button += '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-sm btn-edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editUserModal" id="'+data.userid+'" title="Edit details">';
                    button += '<i class="flaticon2-paper"></i></a>';

                    return button;
                }
```

**my goal is to put the data inside the modal** and my problem is that onclick function is not working when i put it inside a button or a tag, so i tried to use data-target but i dont how to put the data inside the modal with a tags/ button id.